Assumption of Thermal/Chemical Equilibrium in SM Bath
I've been looking at this paper recently, and theres one assumption which I am having some trouble verifying my understanding of. The paper discusses a new neutrino flavor $\nu_s$ (sterile neutrino) with an interaction of the form $\nu_s+\nu_s \leftrightarrow \phi$ with $\phi$ some scalar mediator. The assumption I am talking about is as follows:

...then $2\mu_{\nu_s}=\mu_{\phi}$
While I know that if we know $\Gamma$ we can use the criteria $\Gamma>H$ to determine if the species is in equilibrium, but in this case this would entail a fairly intense computation.
So, for a case like this, my picture is as follows: the sterile neutrinos are essentially isolated from every other species besides $\phi$ and $\nu_s$ itself. The system undergoes a very slow influx of additional $\nu_s$ via $\nu_a$ oscillations. Essentially all we need to assume is that all the $\nu_s$ get "knocked around" frequently enough so that the influx of $\nu_s$ from $\nu_a$ oscillations get pushed into equilibrium quickly. If the interaction is fast enough, I believe this implies equilibrium will be reached. And if $\mu_{\nu_s}>\mu_{\phi}$, we can be somewhat confident that the sterile neutrinos will find another $\nu_s$ quick enough for the process $\nu_s+\nu_s \rightarrow \phi$ to minimize internal energy. If $\mu_{\nu_s}<\mu_{\phi}$, then any $\phi$ can instantly decay to $2\nu_s$--so overall we can assume $2\mu_{\nu_s}\approx \mu_{\phi}$. And since the density of each species is assumed to be fairly low we can ignore quantum effects, leading us to assume a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.
Am I missing any extra important nuances? This seems like a very nontrivial assumption so I would like to ensure I understand it properly. Thank you for any help.
